# SDK for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Where do I get the free SDK for BlackBerry?

Comment: Is it really hard to Google ?

Answer (score 7):

Go [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/started/), sign up and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is on http://na.blackberry.com:
[Java Application Development Tools & Downloads](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp)
[Web Development Tools & Downloads](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/devtoolsdownloads.jsp) 
[BlackBerry Themes Development Tools & Downloads](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/themes/devtools.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on your requirement of the development.

Blackberry support three development environments. Please note that you must have installed necessary java version.

1. Blackberry JDE (Their own development environment). You can select the version according to your target devices.
   http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp
2. Eclips Plugin.
   http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp
3. Microsoft Visual Studio Plugin